# Setting an active state with Vue JS and for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I have a list of strings in Vue, and I'm using `v-for` to list all of them in "list-group" with Bootstrap. I want to set the "active" state on click on one of the items, but I can't find a way to ID a specific item on the list with the for loop.

HTML -

```
<div class="list-group" id="ServersList">
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" v-for="Server in Servers">{{Server.text}}</a>
</div>
```

VueJS -

```
var ServersList = new Vue({
    el: '#ServersList',
    data: {
        Servers: [
            { text: '1' },
            { text: '2' },
            { text: '3' },
            { text: '4' },
            { text: '5' },
            { text: '6' }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `v-for="(Server, index) in Servers"`. Index will store the current index for each element. With this you can then call a defined method like so:

In your viewmodel definition add this:

```
data: {
  currentIndex: 0
},
methods: {
  myClick(index) {
    this.currentIndex = index
  }
}
```

modify your a tag in your template:

```
<a href="#" 
  v-for="(server, index) in Servers" 
  :class="{yourActiveClass: currentIndex === index, yourInactiveClass: currentIndex !== index}" 
  @click="myClick(index)">
```

Comment: Thanks! the thing is I need to use it in the tag itself like <a href="#" id="index">, the main goal is to have some onclick function that changes the "class" element to "list-group-item active"

Comment: You should rather use vue's model of methods. Define a method and bind the index via @click. I'll provide an example in my answer.